# Detect mouse click on movable range tile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D tile game. Assume the Yellow-brownish tile is the Hero character, while the deep blue tiles are movable distances.

On the Hero, a Sprite Renderer, Box Collider 2D and a Rigidbody 2D are added to the game object; layer is Character. The size is 1 x 1 unit and the co-ordinate is (0, 0).

Then, I create 4 movable-range tiles (duplicated from Prefab, size is 1 x 1 unit, layer is Foreground) surrounding the Hero. In order to let `OnMouseDown()` work, I added a Box Collider 2D to the Prefab. After added the collider, problem raised. The hero keeps vibrating, as it is colliding with the 4 movable-range tiles non-stop. How can I stop the collision from happening? *I assume they won't collide if they are in different layers, but in fact they collide!*

Note: can I not using Raycast method (as it will make the codes very complicated)?

Last thing is, I target to make Desktop version as well as mobile version, what is the global way to detect touch & click at the same time?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How have you set up your collision-layer matrix?  Are you sure it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume they won't collide if they are in different layers

Only if you set it up properly. Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics -> Layer Collision Matrix. If a box is checked, the corresponding layers do collide.

> I target to make Desktop version as well as mobile version, what is the global way to detect touch & click at the same time?

Mouse and touch inputs are separated in Unity, so there is no global way, but a single touch can emulate mouse behaviour on mobile platforms (i.e. OnMouseDown() will be triggered), while mouse can't emulate touches (i.e. Input.touches will be empty). So, if it suits you, you can use mouse input on both platforms, otherwise (for example, multitouch is causing troubles) you will have to make platform-dependent controls (for platform defines see http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).